# Is it possible to publish a map service from an SD File purely over REST (no arcpy)?

Tags: python, arcgis-server, map-service

I want to automate the publishing of map services, but without using the arcpy library.

Is it possible to publish a map service from an .SD File purely over REST (no arcpy)?

Comment: Why tag this "python"?

Comment: was actually hoping for an example in python, which is included in jason's answer.  Also had to due with esri's python library arcpy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, *if* you have a service definition (`.sd`) file sitting around. The [`createservice` command line utility which ships with ArcGIS for Server](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Create_Service_utility/015400000622000000/) does not use arcpy. If you [read the source](https://github.com/jasonbot/arcrest/blob/hg/default/arcrest/admin/cmdline.py#L103-179), you will see it does a few things:

1. [Log in to the server and acquire a token](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/server-admin-api/generateToken.html)
2. Find the Publish Service Definition tool on the server
3. [Upload the service draft to the `uploads` folder on the server](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/server-admin-api/uploadItem.html) so the tools on the server know where to find it, get its unique path ID
4. [Call the Publish Service Definition tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/) with the service definition's JSON and path ID of the `.sd` as parameters
5. If successful, [delete the temporary `.sd` file that was uploaded to the server](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/server-admin-api/deleteItem.html)

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to accomplish what you want from the admin api using json. Here is the link to the call server:port/arcgis/admin/services/createService and documentation from the server on how to make the call server:port/arcgis/admin/www/doc/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Been pulling my hair out on this same issue, i managed to publish msd through rest but ArcGIS 10.2 only accepts .sd
so here you go !!! download sample at https://github.com/pheede/agsadmin-devsummit

This is the first working sample i have found. Use the WPf sample, had an async await issue with the console app.
in the mainwindow just add after

```
ags = new ArcGISRESTAdmin.AGSClient(
```

The following line

```
var publishResponse = ags.PublishServiceDefinition(new System.IO.FileInfo(@"C:\......\sdfile.sd"));
```

Do not forget to change the server url, user and password